# PHP fputcsv is returning: "array,array" in stead of the data inside the array

Tags: php, arrays, csv

i'm trying to create a csv file with emailadresses. But when i output the php array with **fputcsv** the output is Array,Array in stead of the data inside the array

I hope someone can help..

i have tried to remove all the lines that start with header(
but then the same output comes to the screen.

Code:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=emails.csv');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
$out = fopen('php://output', 'w');
fputcsv($out, array(
    array('email', 'aantal keer ingevuld'),
    array('ricardo@test.nl', '8')
    )
);
fclose($out);
exit;
```

Output of a var_dump of the array:

```
array(2) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "email" [1]=> string(20) "aantal keer ingevuld" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(24) "ricardo@test.nl" [1]=> string(1) "8" } }
```

output of the csv file:

```
Array,Array
```

**Problem solved**
fputcsv only puts 1 array at a time.
i have to use a loop with a multidimensional array.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: fputcsv() writes 1 line at a time, from a simple array; not an entire file in a single call, from a multidimensional arry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put the fields of the array in separately. Like this:

```
$list = array(
    array('email', 'aantal keer ingevuld'),
    array('ricardo@test.nl', '8')
)   

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($out, $fields);
}
```

Check the documentation on [fputcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php#example-2635) for more information.

Comment: In 8 minutes i can accept your anwser, thanks this worked.